# How Can a String Array Call Generic Select Method with <string,string>

Tags: c#-4.0, extension-methods, ienumerable, generic-programming

I am new to Generic Classes and Generic Methods. I have a simple cpode:

```
Func<string, string> selector = str => str.ToUpper();
string[] words = { "orange", "apple", "Article", "elephant" };
IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Select(selector);
```

When I look at Select method it says:

```
IEnumerable<String> IEnumerable<String>.Select<String, String>(Func<string,string> collector)
```

How does Select generic method knows that String,String types are coming? Does it implicitly come from "selector" delegate? I am really confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler infers the type arguments for `Select` so that you don't have to type them. It burns those types into the compiled assembly.

> Does it implicitly come from "selector" delegate?

Exactly. C# has some type inference so that you have to type less.

The `Select` method itself has no idea what piece of code called it. All it knows is that the type arguments are properly provided.